# Adding geocoding

Tags: geocoding

We would like to be able to email people within 20 miles of a zipcode for our events. We are looking at adding geocoding in Civi. I saw there was an option for Google Geocoding and Open Street Maps.

Have you added geocoding? If so, what did you use and why? How has it worked out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to install the [Geocoder](https://civicrm.org/extensions/geocoder) extension.  This represents a significant improvement on existing geocoding providers.

Google Maps API is now relatively pricey, and Open Street Maps is free.  I find they give roughly comparable quality, but with the Geocoder module you can use multiple geocoders.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder works well.  After you installed and configure it, make sure you turn on the Scheduled Task for geocoding for civicrm to geocode addresses.  Google Map does charge, but depending on your volume of geocoding, you could be remaining within their free tier.